# Adding same text to two different lists

Tags: python

How can I add the same text(s) to two or more different lists?

For example, this is what I am doing:

```
>>> msg = 'Do it'
>>> first = list()
>>> second = list()
>>> first.append(msg)
>>> second.append(msg)
```

Not only this is causing redundancy, I think it makes for poor code. Is there any way I can add the same text to two or more different lists in one go?

Comment: What?  How is this "redundant"?  What are you considering "redundant" about this?  Please be specific on what improvement you think is possible.

Comment: @S.Lott: Redundant as in, in my case I have lots of common text that needs to be appended to the lists. If I keep on adding it one by one, as in my approach above, it is redundant only, isn't it?

Comment: First.  Why two lists?  Second.  How can this be further optimized?  I cannot see any way to remove a single statement from the above.  Please propose something (even if it can't work) so I can get a sense of what you imagine might have less redundancy.

Comment: Two lists because I have to write the two different lists which have the same header. They will differentiate in some way or the other, except for the common text above. SilentGhost has already shown how it can be done, I was trying to get that done. It reduces redundancy since the string that is to be appended to the list is there only as compared to my approach in which it would appear as many times as the string is to be repeated. I was concerned that this would increase the code without any reason.

Comment: "It reduces redundancy"?  How?  How did **adding** a useless loop reduce redundancy?  Is the useless `for` statement less redundant than the two appends?  How?  It's the **same number of lines of code**.  How does that "reduce redundancy"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
first, second = [], []
for lst in (first, second):
    lst.append(msg)
```

But it would be better if you'd tell us what problem are you solving.

Comment: I have some blocks of text that need to be appended to two different lists. I think your approach should work. Wonder why I didn't think of it :)

Comment: @Pulp: why do you have those lists? that's the real question.

Comment: I will be writing these two lists to two separate files. However, the header of both the lists is the same. Hence the common text. (By header I mean, the first two elements of the list are the same)

Comment: @Pulp: I'd rather have a header separate from the rest of the file content then.

Comment: @SilentGhost: Well the biggest problem is that I already have appended the data to the list before hand, and I if I prepend it, won't it slow down things since the entire list will be shifted?

Comment: And to be honest, if I change the way stuff is added to a list, I will go mad :) Thanks for the above though, it serves my purpose well enough for now.

Comment: @PulpFiction The point if it slow down things depends only on the size of the list, not the size of list content because list contains only pointers to elements.

Answer (score 3):

This is inefficient. Why not make one list and then `copy()` it when you need to differentiate the two?

```
msg = 'Do it'
theList = [ ]
theList.append( msg )
# Later...
first = theList
second = theList.copy( )
```

#### EDIT

I saw your edit. Why not do:

```
header = [ ]
# Generate header here.
# Later...
for theFile in theFiles:
    theFile.write( header )
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need keeping 2 identical lists, instead of one? Describe your task in more details.

Comment: Only some text is identical, I will add some text later that will differentiate the lists.

Answer (score 0):

Without the write trick
If you have to set the first element after the construction of the list because you don't know it before the simplest is to reserve the place

```
first, second = [], []
for lst in (first, second):
    lst.append(None)
... work on your lists
msg = 'Do it'
for lst in (first, second):
    lst[0] = msg
```